# Cardinality of $A \cup B$ given $A$ and $B$ are finite.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

Given finite sets $A, B,$ we want to show that the cardinality of $A \cup B$ is given by
$$|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B| $$
where $|S| $ denotes the number of elements of a finite set $S$.

My argument is as follows: Since $A$ and $B$ are finite, $A\cup B$ is finite. We count the number of elements of $A\cup B.$ Now, any element of $A\cup B$ must belong to either $A$ or $B$. Thus we count all the elements of $A$ and also count all the elements of $B$, adding them together. However, if there are elements common to both $A$ and $B$, we would have counted them twice, once as elements of $A$ and once as elements of $B.$ Thus we must subtract these, that is, we must discount elements of $A\cap B.$

Hence $|A\cup B|$ = $|A|$ + $|B|$ - $|A\cap B|.$

While I believe my reasoning is sound, I am not sure how to formalize this. Please see if this is correct and suggest ways to write the same.

Answer (score 1):

To formalize a bit your proof in a more mathematical way :

- If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$.
- If $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint, then $|A\setminus B|=|A|-|A\cap B|$. Indeed, $A\setminus B$ and $A\cap B$ are disjoint and s.t. $A=(A\setminus B)\cup A\cap B$.
- Finally, since $$A\cup B=(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B)\cup (B\setminus A)$$ and that the union is disjoin, you finally get your formula.

Comment: You could also write that $A\cup B=(A\setminus B)\cup B$ and since the union is disjoint, you get that $|A\cup B|=|A\setminus B|+|B|$ that is $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$